# Creation of a new instance of generic type parameter not getting code coverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've run my code through code coverage and the line below shows 1 block as not covered.

Can anyone tell me which part of that line isn't executing?

[image]

An Example to play with:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract IExample CreateEntity<TExample>() where TExample : IExample, new();
}

public class Class1 : Base
{
    public override IExample CreateEntity<TExample>()
    {
        IExample temp = new TExample();
        return temp;
    }
}

public interface IExample
{

}

public class TEx : IExample
{

}
```

and the test method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Class1 ex = new Class1();
        ex.CreateEntity<TEx>();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try dropping `temp` to make it `return new TExample()`?

Comment: Is `info` referenced anywhere?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight [it still reports 20% non-coverage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JXdb8.png) even if it is one line, weird.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Interesting... My version of VS (Pro) does not support code coverage, so I cannot play with your code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your constraint to force the `TExample` to be a class:

```
public abstract IExample CreateEntity<TExample>() where TExample : class, IExample, new();
```

If you run your compiled code through a tool like ILSpy, you will see the block that is not getting coverage:

```
TExample temp = (default(TExample) == null) ? Activator.CreateInstance<TExample>() : default(TExample);
return temp;
```

It is performing a check to see if the type passed to the generic was a reference type or a value type. By forcing it to be a class, this check will be removed.  Read more on the default keyword here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

Another way to get complete code coverage would be to use a struct that implements `IExample`:

```
public struct S1 : IExample
{ 
}
```

And then add this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StructTest()
{
    Class1 ex = new Class1();
    ex.CreateEntity<S1>();
}
```